# converting js comfirm box to lightbox

Tags: javascript, lightbox, confirm

I have a `confirm()` JS code and it's working just fine. Basically it's a small function that displays a textual message depending on the value I sent (1 or 2), pressing the ok button will take them to a pdf file. However, when I use it in firefox, it shows the "Prevent this page from showing additional content" dialog box and I can't format the text inside it.

I'm looking for guidance on how to convert it using lightbox/modal.
My code:

```
    <script language="javascript">
function confdl(distext,fname) 
{
    if (distext == "1")
    {
    var answer = confirm("Message 1 goes here.")
    }
    else
    {
    var answer = confirm("Message 2 goes here.")        
    }
    if (answer){
        window.location = ("/path/to/pdf/file/"+fname);
    }
    else{

    }
}
</script>

<a  href="javascript:confdl('1','file1.pdf');">PDF 1</a>
<a  href="javascript:confdl('2','file2.pdf');">PDF 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using `confirm`, however, when displayed more than once in google Chrome, it will show a checkbox to let the user prevent alerts from popping up. This is a feature from chrome to prevent unwanted popups from annoying or even malicious sites.

You should be just fine using confirm in your scenario, but you won't be able to remove that checkbox from the chrome popups.

If you are looking for a more modern solution, with full control over the message display, you should use modal dialogs for that. It looks way better. Since is your own HTML, you can style it any way you want with CSS.

If you want to speed things up, there are many libraries available. As an example, take a look how this library replaces the default javascript popup boxes with customizable modals: https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/

Comment: thank you. the page has been using confirm() for years and i just took over helping them to change things around - i'm still learning as i go.  it's just that some of the users keep asking what that box for , they're not technical like you :)

Answer (score 0):

i think i got it :)

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         var linkno;

         function setLink(ind,msgtype) {
             linkno = ind;
    var div = document.getElementById('modalMsg');
    if (msgtype == "1")
     {
     div.innerHTML = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sed lectus viverra, posuere mauris vel, faucibus massa. Fusce dui elit, ultricies quis aliquam et, pulvinar dictum ipsum. Etiam molestie arcu nec ipsum condimentum dignissim. Suspendisse et tempor orci, id accumsan mi. Pellentesque pellentesque ante vitae tortor vestibulum fringilla. Duis aliquam vel elit at molestie. Etiam vehicula libero id quam facilisis dictum. Pellentesque ultrices justo at feugiat luctus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent at dolor risus. Suspendisse sollicitudin vel purus ut ultrices. Cras libero est, lacinia et convallis vel, scelerisque quis lacus. Etiam condimentum orci sed urna finibus aliquet.';
    }
    else
    {
     div.innerHTML = 'Aliquam ut magna id est ornare imperdiet pellentesque tempus nisl. Fusce congue, turpis eu consequat pulvinar, massa tortor laoreet elit, nec dignissim felis neque non mauris. Aliquam non aliquet orci. Vivamus blandit at leo quis fringilla. Praesent sed est aliquet, porttitor nulla nec, finibus leo. Duis pellentesque id elit et porta. Nunc ullamcorper eget odio vitae accumsan. Quisque fermentum urna et nisl aliquet venenatis. Curabitur nec dignissim turpis. Nam dapibus tincidunt tincidunt. Ut vulputate ornare dictum. Donec ligula lectus, vestibulum at tellus ut, laoreet sagittis nunc. Sed malesuada aliquam lacus, eu suscipit justo dignissim luctus. Nullam eget mattis dolor. Ut ut ornare sem. ';
     
    }
   }
         // modal box related functions
         $(document).ready(function() {
             var triggers = $(".modalInput").overlay({

                 // some mask tweaks suitable for modal dialogs
                 mask: {
                     color: '#ebecff',
                     loadSpeed: 200,
                     opacity: 0.9
                 },

                 closeOnClick: false
             });

             $("#btnContinue").click(function(e) {
                 // close the overlay
                 window.location = triggers.eq(linkno).overlay().getTrigger().attr("href");
             });

         });
```

```css
    .modal {
        background-color:#e9e9e9;
        display:none;
        width:550px;
        padding:15px;
        text-align:left;
        border:1px solid #999999;
        opacity:0.8;
        -moz-border-radius:6px;
        -webkit-border-radius:6px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #ccc;
        margin:auto auto auto auto;
    }

    .modal #modalTitle {
        margin:20px 0 0 0;
        padding:10px 0 10px 0;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:14px;
    }
    
    .modal #modalMsg 
    {
        border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        color:#333333;
        padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }
 .buttonlinks a
 {
  padding:4px;
  margin:4px;
  background:#f3f3f3;
  border:1px solid #cecece;
 }
```

```html
    <div id="extlink" class="modal" style="display: none;">
        <a class="close" style="cursor:pointer;float: right; margin: 5px 0pt 0pt;" class="close">Close</a>
        <div id="modalTitle">Disclaimer:</div>
    
        <div id="modalMsg"></div>
    
        <!-- yes/no buttons -->
        <div style="float: right; margin: 20px 0pt 0pt;">
            <a id="btnContinue">Continue</a>
            <a class="close">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
 <div class="buttonlinks">    
     <a href="http://www.pic.cx/img97/ijtasctqvznzrgoidrxr.jpg" class='modalInput' rel='#extlink' onclick='setLink(0,1)' target="_blank">Site 1</a>
     <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.png" class='modalInput' rel='#extlink' onclick='setLink(0,2)' target="_blank">Site 2</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: You are using modal dialogs. This is exactly what I told you to do in my answer.

Comment: i spoke too soon  ... i have 2 links to point to 2 different urls, the modal show up just fine, but the continue button always take me to the first link ... could you please take a look and show me how to fix that?

Comment: also since the link are mostly to pdf, the browser will ask user to open/save when clicking on the continue button - and that keep the modal box stay open...is there a way to close it after continue was clicked?

Comment: you should create a javascript function instead of a direct link. The function will first close the modal, and then load the pdf using `window.location = 'pdf url..'`